# How to select option in dropdown list if it has no value set (selenium webdriver-js)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have following dropdown on the site:

```
<select id="deliveryType">
<option value>Please select</option>
<option value>No delivery</option>
<option value>Delivery One</option>
<option value>Delivery Two</option></select>
```

and I need to select "No Delivery"

My automation framework is in javascript (node.js) and test step looks like:

```
 this.driver.findElement(By.css([id=deliveryType])).click();
```

How do I choose an option given that value is not set> I either need "No delivery" but logic like "give me element #2" would work as well?

Comment: you can use xpath, right ?

Comment: I eventually found a solution which fit me -> to call option by its text, e.g.
this.driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="deliveryType"]/option[text()='No delivery'])).click()

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `By.xpath` selector and do something like:

```
this.driver
  .findElement(By.css([id=deliveryType]))
  .findElement(By.xpath(option[2])).click();
```